# How to split a string by underscore and extract an element as a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a string such like `s=DNA128533_mutect2_filtered.vcf.gz`. How could I extract the `DNA128533` as an ID variable.

I tried

```
id=(cut -d_ -f1 <<< ${s}
echo $id
```

It seems not working. some suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to spend a sub-shell calling `cut -d'_' -f1` and using bashism `<<< "$s"`.

The POSIX shell grammar has built-in provision for stripping-out the trailing elements with variable expansion, without forking a costly sub-shell or using non-standard Bash specific `<<<"here string"`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

s=DNA128533_mutect2_filtered.vcf.gz
id=${s%%_*}
echo "$id"
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to filter the DNA... part out of the filename.  Therefore:

```
s="DNA128533_mutect2_filtered.vcf.gz"

id=$(echo "$s" | cut -d'_' -f1)
echo "$id"
```

If you want to use your way of doing it (with `<<<`), do this:

```
id=$(cut -d'_' -f1 <<< "$s")
echo "$id"
```

Your command has some syntax issues, like you are missing `)`.
And you want the output of the command to be stored in variable `id`, so you have to make it run via the `$( )` syntax.

Comment: Why do you do stuff more complicated than needed? `id=${s%%_*}`

Comment: I reused the OPs syntax, by fixing it.  But you are right, variable expansion works.

Answer (score 3):

`IFS` is the bash way delimiter, we can cut string as below:

```
IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< "a_b_c_d"
echo "${array[0]}"
```

Comment: `IFS` the the fields delimiter for any POSIX shell, and not only Bash. It remains the right setting to split strings to words with the argument array: `str='a_b_c_d'; IFS=_; set -- $str; echo "$1"` → prints `a`.